# Error message obtained in determining the k-number of cluster of K-Means clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I would like to determine k-number of cluster but I couldn't use the NbClust function because my dataset is too big.

I found an article on-line regarding to K-Means clustering http://www.r-bloggers.com/k-means-clustering-from-r-in-action/. I tried to run the function in the article, but I got the below error message.

Does anyone has solutions for either NbClust function or the function stated in the article?

```
> wssplot <- function(m, nc=15, seed=1234){
+   wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))
+   for (i in 2:nc){
+     set.seed(seed)
+     wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers=i)$withinss)}
+   plot(1:nc, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
+        ylab="Within groups sum of squares")}

> wssplot(m3)
 Error in apply(data, 2, var) : dim(X) must have a positive length


> nc <- NbClust(m3, min.nc=2, max.nc=20, method="kmeans")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 447.3 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.factor(x) :
  Reached total allocation of 8139Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In is.factor(x) :
```

Comment: You're transcribing the code from the blog incorrectly. The code passes an argument `data` and then uses that in the function's code. You pass an argument `m` and then use `data` in the function's code. I'm surprised it runs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

1. fixing the problem with your dimensionality / data layout in `wssplot`
2. Considered using sampling to use a smaller data set
3. Doing the process manually: cluster with k=2 first, then k=3, and then compare the scores of the results?

First make sure your data is appropriate for k-means: can you compute means?